# Make xelatex cache font families in Windows 7?

Tags: xetex, texlive, fontspec, windows

I'm using TeXLive + TeXMaker to write a paper and I need to include the font Scala Sans Pro, which I have as a set of otf files in the local directory as part of the file. After much wrangling with lcdftools I was only able to install the Regular version of the font, and then I finally gave up and started using xelatex.

Now I can get it to work, but it's *slooooow*, every single time, and much slower since I switched to importing it like this (which is necessary to get BoldItalics to work):

```
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setsansfont[
Extension       = .otf,
Path            = Fonts/ScalaSansPro/,
UprightFont     = *-Regular,
BoldFont        = *-Bold,
ItalicFont      = *-Italic,
BoldItalicFont  = *-BoldItalic]{ScalaSansPro}
```

It's taking like 5+ minutes for every single build. I don't mind waiting 5-10 minutes to build the document once, but is there some way to have TeXLive or TexMaker cache the font so I don't have to build it every time? Otherwise this would be intolerable.

(The way I used to do it it would take 30-60 second to build, and that was by using `\setsansfont(ScalaSansPro)`, but for whatever reason ScalaSansPro-BoldItalic installed as a separate font, so bold-italics weren't detected by xelatex

**Edit:** The 5-10 minute thing has stopped, so maybe it's already cache-ing - but it's still pretty slow (30-60 second build times, significantly slower than pdflatex was). I'll leave this question up and hopefully someone can explain if this is a font problem or what.

Comment: Even tough it may seem trivial to you, could you complement your code to be a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), i.e. it should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Also, if I wanted to try to reproduce your problem, where could I get Scala Sans Pro from?

Comment: OK, I'll edit the code tonight. As far as I know you'd have to buy Scala Sans Pro or have it come as part of a software package or something.

Comment: Is there any other font that yields a similar problem? (One that a lot of people have or that you can get easily = freely)